# Gear S2 - Failed install native app error [83] [73]

Tags: installation, watch, tizen

I am trying to develop my first application for my Samsung Gear S2. I created the native project BasicUI, when I try to run the app on the emulator it works fine, but when it comes to my watch the process fails at the installation, and it says:

> Cannot install application. Unknown Error [83]

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening ?

I already activated the option "Unknown sources" for my watch with the Gear app on my phone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it. I hadn't installed the **Certificate Extension**.

This link helped me a lot: http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/getting-certificates/create

Here is the main steps anyway :

First install **Certificate Extension** if you haven't yet, close Tizen IDE, open Tizen Update Manager, and install Certificate Extension which you will find in **Extras** section.
Then, you have to get the DUID of your watch (Device Unique IDentifier). Open again Tizen IDE, connect your watch to your computer, and right click on your device in the **Connection Explorer** section, **Properties**, copy the DUID.
Click on this icon in the toolbar: [image: icon] and create a new certificate.
You should past your DUID in step 4.

Once it is done, you may have to upload the certificate to your device: right click on your device in **Connection Explorer** and **Permit to install applications**. That's it. You can now upload your apps to the Gear.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Actually, this is just the thing I've been struggling with. My error was Unknown 81. It helped me out as I've been looking through the Tizen documentation, and they say it nicely there but not to this depth of specifics. :) Thanks. I'd only add here that since Samsung Gear 2 is a bit buggy and has a bit unreliable connection, there is a need for some retries to establish the connection with the device. And sometimes restarting of the Tizen(Eclipse) IDE helps too...

Comment: You're welcome :) Yeah a bit buggy... By the way I'm still searching some tutorials on internet if you know some good ones, please let me know :)

Comment: sadly no.. I haven't found anything really useful except the example apps that you can get in the Tizen IDE. I'm having lots of trouble with simple connection to the API atm. If I find any useful tutorial, I will be sure to share it. :)

Comment: URL is changed to http://developer.samsung.com/gear/develop/getting-certificates/create